# Ошибка при получении данных из БД (Could not convert variant of type (String) into type (Currency))

Tags: delphi, sql-server, delphi-7, типы-данных

У меня в БД (SQL Server) лежат данные в виде `decimal(18, 3)`. При попытке их получить в виде текста, у меня возникает вот такая ошибка. Вот мой код:

```
  stat1.Panels.Items[1].Text:='1: '+dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('tarif_som').AsVariant;
  stat1.Panels.Items[2].Text:='2: '+dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('takasa_som').AsVariant;
  stat1.Panels.Items[3].Text:='3: '+dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('dop_zbor_napravSom').AsVariant;
  stat1.Panels.Items[4].Text:='4: '+dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('shtraf_som').AsVariant;
  stat1.Panels.Items[5].Text:='5: '+dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('CannelCoastSom').AsVariant;
```

Вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> EVariantTypeCastError with message 'Could not convert variant of type (String) into type (Currency)'.

Как мне быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте получать данные на в виде `AsVariant`, а сразу в нужном типе - `AsString`:

```
... := dbgrd1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldbyName('...').AsString;
```